# Microsoft SQL Server duplicate results from query

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    ShipperName, S.ShipmentID, DepartureDate
FROM 
    SHIPMENT S, SHIPMENT_ITEM SI
WHERE 
    S.ShipmentID = SI.ShipmentID
    AND Value > 1000
ORDER BY 
    ShipperName ASC, DepartureDate DESC;
```

Returns these results:

```
International                       4   2013-06-02
International                       4   2013-06-02
International                       4   2013-06-02
Worldwide                           3   2013-05-05
```

The first three results are identical but what I am looking for is this:

```
International                       4   2013-06-02
Worldwide                           3   2013-05-05
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: If you want distinct row you must add after **SELECT** and before fields **DISTINCT** but I think if you ask this question you do not know your data or you do not know SQL

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting data that appear to come exclusively from the Shipment table (`ShipperName`, `S.ShipmentID`, `DepartureDate`), but you are joining that table to the `ShipmentItem` table, which apparently may have more than one row per Shipment.  Your joined table has one row for each item (that is related to a shipment in the Shipment table).

Evidently you want only *shipments* that contain at least one item having `value` greater than 1000, but as your query is written you will get a result row for each *item* with such a value.  The simplest way to achieve what you want is probably just to add the `DISTINCT` keyword to your query, as others have suggested.  There are other alternatives, though, some of which might be more appropriate for different, more complex requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the DISTINCT keyword on your select statement.

Like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ShipperName, S.ShipmentID, DepartureDate
FROM SHIPMENT S, SHIPMENT_ITEM SI
WHERE S.ShipmentID = SI.ShipmentID
AND Value > 1000
ORDER BY ShipperName ASC, DepartureDate DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ShipperName
         , S.ShipmentID
         , DepartureDate
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ShipperName ORDER BY ShipperName) rn
    FROM SHIPMENT S 
    INNER JOIN SHIPMENT_ITEM SI
    ON S.ShipmentID = SI.ShipmentID
    WHERE Value > 1000
    ORDER BY ShipperName ASC, DepartureDate DESC
)
SELECT ShipperName
      ,ShipmentID
      ,DepartureDate
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EXPLICIT join as implicit JOIN is outdated and deprecated

you seem to have multiple entries matching with shipment id, use distinct key word or you might be missing a join on some column

```
SELECT distinct ShipperName, S.ShipmentID, DepartureDate
FROM SHIPMENT S
JOIN SHIPMENT_ITEM SI
ON S.ShipmentID = SI.ShipmentID
AND Value > 1000
ORDER BY ShipperName ASC, DepartureDate DESC;
```